# Linking with a shared object file in my home directory

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gdb, ld

I have a shared object file which I'd like to link with.  The file is currently located in my home directory - it's *not* located in a normal library directory like `/usr/lib`, because I am simply testing and do not have permissions to deploy it yet to `/usr/lib`.

So, I try to compile and link with it as follows:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -L. mylib.so -g3
```

The compiler returns no error, however, when I run I get the error:

```
./test: error while loading shared libraries: mylib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Okay, so after some Googling around I realized the problem was that my library *run path* does not include my home directory, so I need to pass an `rpath` option to the linker when compiling.  Okay, so I try:

```
 g++ test.cpp -o test -Wl,-rpath,. -L. mylib.so -g3
```

This compiles fine, however when I run the program it immediately seg faults.

So, I use `gdb` to see what's going on:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: ~/test
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

A backtrace reveals no useful information.  There is a single stackframe:

```
#0  0x0000000000400808 in main () at test.cpp:13
```

So, I'm sure this is likely a problem with the way I am compiling and linking, but googling around for this issue doesn't turn up much of an answer.

What are some possible or likely causes of the "**`no loadable sections found ...`**" error message?  Does this indicate the runtime environment is unable to find certain libraries?  The `.so` file was compiled using the `-fPIC` and `-shared` flags.

Comment: "So, I'm sure this is likely a problem with the way I am compiling and linking" - quite the opposite. it probably has nothing to do with it. post minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

> What are some possible or likely causes of the "no loadable sections found ..." error message?

It's a GDB warning you can safely ignore.

> Does this indicate the runtime environment is unable to find certain libraries?

On the contrary, it indicates that your program is starting fine, and runs to line 13 of `test.cpp` (which is long past initialization), then crashes.

Unfortunately, you didn't show what line 13 looks like, so it's impossible to help you more.